# Trying to get brightness values of this picture across the x axis

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

For some comparison in light diffusers I would like to make a script that gives me some values, this would mean that I could get the brightness of the pixels (or x amount) along a straight line through the middle. I've been trying to get it to work but only manage to get an overall brightness lvl. [Pic of code p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJpuL.png)
[Pic of code p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLkVp.png)
[Pic of code p3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFQKC.png)

```
imag = Image.open(image)
#Convert the image te RGB if it is a .gif for example
imag = imag.convert ('RGB')
#coordinates of the pixel
X,Y = 0,0
#Get RGB
pixelRGB = imag.getpixel((X,Y))
R,G,B = pixelRGB 

brightness = sum([R,G,B])/3 ##0 is dark (black) and 255 is bright (white)
```

Looking to get an array across the x axis with the brightness values
[Result I look for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34LXU.png)

thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please avoid [posting images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please post your actual image, rather than a figure with axes and extraneous junk/stuff. Thank you.